# Jmeter Custom Graph: How to export graphs from exported results of PerfMon Metrics Collector Plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, perfmon

I have an objective: 
   to generate graphs from the values which got exported from the PerfMon plugin.
   The exported values like cpu usage in percent, DiskIO-Read\Write in bytes etc are exported in csv which has same headers as of jmeter view results config csv file. [*which is bit surprising for me :)]

Solution Seeking: I need to get graphs based on cpu usage, DiskIO, Network Sent\Received,Memory etc. which are being exported in this csv.

Sample data which is written out by this PerfMon plugin is shown below for reference:
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Filename,Latency,Encoding,SampleCount,ErrorCount,Hostname,IdleTime,Connect
2020/05/07 15:37:52.567,0,MACHINE1 Disks I/O 884_DQueue,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:52.567,0,MACHINE1 Disks I/O 884_DReadBytes,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:52.567,0,MACHINE1 Disks I/O 884_DWriteBytes,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:52.567,1902,MACHINE1 CPU 884_CPU,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:52.567,30375,MACHINE1 Memory 884_MUsedPercent,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,1013,MACHINE2 CPU,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,0,MACHINE2 Disks I/O DiskReadBytes,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,76604,MACHINE2 Memory MemUsedPerc,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,844384272000,MACHINE2 Disks I/O DiskAvailable,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,0,MACHINE2 Network I/O NtkRecBy,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,0,MACHINE2 Memory MemPageFaults,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,0,MACHINE2 Network I/O NtkSentBy,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,0,MACHINE2 Disks I/O DiskWriteBytes,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,0,MACHINE2 Disks I/O DiskQueues,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,0,MACHINE3 Disks I/O 883_DWriteBytes,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0
2020/05/07 15:37:53.572,30876,MACHINE3 Memory 883_MUsedPercent,,,,,true,,0,0,0,0,null,,0,ISO-8859-1,1,0,localhost,0,0

My question is how can I create graphs from this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the chart from "this csv" using [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/) as simple as:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-png perfmon.png --input-jtl perfmon.csv --plugin-type PerfMon
```

JMeter Plugins Command Line tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]

More information: [How to Use the JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line)